# get multiple records in one query in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Lets say I have a Cat table and each cat has a unique color.   Is there an activerecord method I can use to get the red and the blue cat in one query.  My goal is a faster query than having to find each one individually with Cat.where(color: red) then doing the same thing with blue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
Cat.where(color: ['red', 'blue'])
```

this will generate SQL query:

`SELECT cats.* FROM cats WHERE cats.color IN ('red', 'blue')`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it this way at first but didn't know the values needed to be in an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cat.where(color: 'red').or.where(color: 'blue')
```

or

```
Cat.where("color = ? OR color = ?", "red", "blue")
```

or

```
Cat.where(color: ["red", "blue"])
```

Answer (score -1):

research    `JOIN` statement

you can also use `OR` in where

```
where (color='blue' OR color='green')
```

check:

[Join statement - toturialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)

[OR and AND expression](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php)

Comment: Please, [do not link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com/) as the advice it provides is often incomplete, misleading, or dangerously out of date. Additionally, this not the case for a `JOIN`.

Comment: @tadman mind removing the negative please? i am trying my hardest to be able to ask again. it has been fixed long ago.

Comment: I'm not trying to be overly harsh here, but there are two other great answers that are straight to the point. `JOIN` is not an issue here. We all miss the mark sometimes. Just delete your answer unless you can come up with a better one than the other, or at least demonstrate how `JOIN` might be a factor as it's not clear what you're getting at. It's not a big deal, there's no harm done, just a matter of keeping things uncluttered. I've had to delete many false-start answers. If you do, the down votes disappear.